# Kendo Multiselect breaks page layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, multi-select

I have a page with a Kendo grid and several controls.

[image]

It works fine, no problem here.
I have to replace the kendo dropdownlist with a kendo multiselect. 
And then this happened

[image]

The layout is all messed up and the grid stops working.

I change the control back to kendo dropdownlist and everything goes back to normal.

The multiselect works fine, but everything else gets messed up.

This is the code for the dropdown

```
  @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
              .Name("Something")
              .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:200px" })
              .OptionLabel("Select Something...")
              .DataTextField("Text")
              .DataValueField("Value")
              .BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>
              {
                  new SelectListItem
                  {
                      Text = "SomeValue",
                      Value = "SomeValue"
                  },
                  ...
                  new SelectListItem
                  {
                      Text = "SomeValue",
                      Value = "SomeValue"
                  } }))
```

And this the code for the multiselect, OptionLabel changes to PlaceHolder, that's the only change

```
 @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
              .Name("region")
              .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:200px" })
              .Placeholder("Select Something...")
              .DataTextField("Text")
              .DataValueField("Value")
              .BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>
              {
                      new SelectListItem
                      {
                          Text = "SomeValue",
                          Value = "SomeValue"
                      },
                      ...
                      new SelectListItem
                      {
                          Text = "SomeValue",
                          Value = "SomeValue"
                      } }))
```

Any ideas?

Tks in advance.

Comment: Try reducing the hard specified width attributes on the controls, or better yet use percentages instead. Take a look in the console window at the CSS elements applied to the multiselect aswell, perhaps there is additional padding applied?

Comment: I've tried already, that is not the problem.